# Can we import Magento products to the Wordpress?

Tags: e-commerce, magento

Can we import Magento products to the word press? For example, let just say I have an e-commerce site in Magento and blog is developed in WP. Now I want to pull the Magento customer wishlist products to the word press.

Is there an easy way to implement this? perhaps an extension? so far I couldn't find it. If you could shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Magento and WordPress are 2 different things. WordPress is a Content Management System (CMS) that allows you to create Pages / posts. Magento is an e-commerce platform that allows you to sell products. There are plenty of e-commerce *plugins* for WordPress that you can install, and then import your Magento products into the database for that particular plugin. I can't say how, since whatever plugin you choose will have different instructions. The most popular e-commerce plugin for WordPress is WooCommerce http://woocommerce.com/ and then you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart2cart-magento-to-woocommerce-migration/ to migrate your data.

If you want to simply integrate Magento with WordPress so that you can utilize the products from magento in WordPress side-by-side then yes it's probably possible. https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/ you can checkout this plugin to help you do that.